# Change PDF file name with names from list with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a list of new filenames that like to be applied to a list of files in google drive.

I have the FileID and corresponding new filenames in a google sheet (*column1* with FilesIDs, *column2* with the new filenames)

The solutions i found all had to do with renaming from *Old-name* to *New-name*.
I'm looking for a method to rename google drive files using the *FileID*

[image]

What would the script look like? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `a list` of `I have a list of new filenames that like to be applied to a list of files in google drive.`. Unfortunately, I cannot image about it. I apologize for this. 2. Can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changenames() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const dt=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  dt.forEach(function(r){DriveApp.getFileById(r[0]).setName(r[1])});
}
```

Comment: This seems to be doing it to the first row only.

Comment: I accidently put `getLastColumn()` instead of `getLastRow()`

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks!